# How render two different contents of a modal window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon, I have a modal window in which the content is displayed depending on the condition.

I can't to do when the subscription is disabled, the content of the modal changed to "Subscription successful disabled".
And when you click on the "Enable subscription" button, the content of the modal changed to "Enable subscription by clicking on the button"

Now it turns out that "Subscription successful disabled" and "Enable subscription by clicking on the button" are displayed at once.
The enableSub and disableSub functions emulate sending data to the server, and the state emulates receiving data from the server.

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

const state = {
  isSubscriptionEnabled: true,
}

const enableSub = () => {
  state.isSubscriptionEnabled = true
}
const disableSub = () => {
  state.isSubscriptionEnabled = false
}


function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  return ( <
    div > {
      isOpen &&
      < div className = "modalWrapper" >
      <
      div className = "modal" >
      <
      button onClick = {
        () => setIsOpen(false)
      } > close < /button> <
      div > {
        state.isSubscriptionEnabled &&
        < div >
        Are you sure disable subscription ?
        <
        button className = "button"
        onClick = {
          disableSub
        } >
        Disalbe subscription <
        /button> <
        /div>
      } {
        !state.isSubscriptionEnabled &&
          < div >
          Subscription successful disabled <
          button onClick = {
            () => setIsOpen(false)
          } > Thanks < /button> <
          /div>
      } {
        !state.isSubscriptionEnabled &&
          < div >
          Enable subscription by clicking on button <
          button className = "button"
        onClick = {
            enableSub
          } >
          Enable subscription <
          /button> <
          /div>
      } <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    }

    {
      state.isSubscriptionEnabled &&
        < button className = "button"
      onClick = {
          () => setIsOpen(true)
        } >
        Disalbe subscription <
        /button>
    } {
      !state.isSubscriptionEnabled &&
        < button className = "button"
      onClick = {
          () => setIsOpen(true)
        } >
        Enable subscription <
        /button>
    } <
    /div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.app {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px;
}

.modalWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq82ej0v/)

Comment: Your global object "state" does not trigger render, you need to use React API for that, move it to component state like you have done with Open

Comment: @DennisVash this code its just an example, code on my project works good. I just want to know how to render depending on the state

Answer (score 0):

```
import {React,useState} from 'react'

function App() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isSubscriptionEnabled, enableSubscription] = useState(false)
    const enableSub = () => {
      enableSubscription(true)
    }
    const disableSub = () => {
        enableSubscription(false)
    }

  return ( 
    <div> {
      isOpen &&
      <div className = "modalWrapper" >
      <div className = "modal" >
      <button onClick = {
        () => setIsOpen(false)
      } > close </button> 
      <div> {
        isSubscriptionEnabled&&
        <div>
            Are you sure disable subscription ?
        <button className = "button"
            onClick = {
            disableSub
            } >
            Disable subscription 
        </button> 
        </div>
      } {
        !isSubscriptionEnabled&&
          <div>
          Subscription successful disabled 
          <button onClick = {
            () => setIsOpen(false)
          } > Thanks </button> 
          </div>
      } {
        !isSubscriptionEnabled&&
          <div>
            Enable subscription by clicking on button 
            <button className = "button"
                onClick = {
                    enableSub
                } >
                Enable subscription 
            </button> 
            </div>
        } </div> 
        </div> 
        </div>
    }

    {
      isSubscriptionEnabled&&
        <button className = "button"
            onClick = {
                () => setIsOpen(true)
                } >
            Disable subscription 
        </button>
    } {
      !isSubscriptionEnabled&&
        <button className = "button"
            onClick = {
                () => setIsOpen(true)
                } >
            Enable subscription 
        </button>
    } 
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

React components only render when we change a component using its useState inside that particular component. it will not rerender on your global variable

Please try to format your code at least before posting here,